# LTE downlink Mimo

Tags: digital-communications

How does a base station decide whether it is going to use open loop spatial multiplexing or closed loop spatial multiplexing in LTE? 
I know that it relies on feedback from the UE which does not include PMI (prefered matrix index) in case of open loop spatial multiplexing.
Does that mean that it is the UE that decides? and based on which criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the base station configuration. For open loop spatial multiplexing, it does not need to use feedback from the UE like PMI. That doesn't mean that the UE is deciding, or that the UE is not sending PMI for open loop spatial multiplexing. Just that the base station doesn't need the information, and can ignore it if it is sent by the UE.